# Create ASP.NET Roles and Membership table to DB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I  created a db called Antune.

I need to create the ASP.NET Roles and Forms tables to my existing db. 
I looked to see where aspnet_regsql.exe is located but found about 7 of those on my computer.
Which one do I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whichever one matches the version of asp.net you are using.

e.g. if you are using 32 bit asp.net 2, use the one in the `windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.xxxxx` folder.

Comment: Correct.  Match the version of your code base (the Framework it is being developed in) to the aspnet_regsql.exe).

Comment: When I ran the following code - string s = Environment.Version.ToString(); I got 4.0.30319.296. I there supposed to be Framwork\v4... someplace? If so, I am not finding it

Comment: Yes, there should be a c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319